# How to make SQL query with empty date?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I want to make this query:

```
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection conn= null;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis","postgres","123456");
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String sql = "SELECT num FROM parcels WHERE code_initial_right =(SELECT code_document FROM documents WHERE number_document=? or date_document='"+docd+"')";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1,docn);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

But `docd` can be equals `null`. When i try this i get an error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""
```

What can i do with this?

Comment: How about using `if`. :)

Comment: How appending or date_document='"+docd+" to String sql only when is not null?

Comment: You mean use `if` in case when `docd=null` assign `docd` to randomdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `if`:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT num FROM parcels WHERE code_initial_right =");
if (docd != null) {
   sql.append("(SELECT code_document FROM documents WHERE number_document=? or date_document='"+docd+"')");
}else {
   sql.append("(SELECT code_document FROM documents WHERE number_document=?)");
}
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
```

Comment: Yeah its will 100% works. But i thought that i can find something in SQL or jdbc functions(

Answer (score 3):

Use the `IS NULL` predicate:

```
....
OR docd IS NULL OR date_document = docd;
```

Comment: @KliverMax - Sorry, I write `docd` with `$` to indicate that it is a parameter, you have to write it with the proper way with Java. I edited my answer.

Comment: @ Mahmoud Gamal in answer you mean `OR date_document IS NULL OR date_document = docd;`? Couse i get error: `ERROR: column "docd" does not exist`.

Comment: But if i use `OR date_document IS NULL OR date_document = docd;`  i get erorr:  `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""`

Answer (score 1):

try **ISNULL**(date_document, default_date) like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT num FROM parcels WHERE code_initial_right =(SELECT code_document FROM documents WHERE number_document=? or isnull(date_document, '"+docd+"') ='"+docd+"')";
```

Comment: `ERROR: function isnull(date, unknown) does not exist`

Comment: @KliverMax ok, try this: String sql = "SELECT num FROM parcels WHERE code_initial_right =(SELECT code_document FROM documents WHERE number_document=? or NULLIF(date_document, '"+docd+"') ='"+docd+"')";